# Use a db class of just check get and post variables?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm writing a web application and i'm thinking about sql injections.
I have created a database class that trough an array can makes everything, forgetting about escaping strings.
That class works likes that:

```
$db->q(array(
'SELECT' => 'username',
'FROM' => USERS_TABLE, 
'WHERE' => array('user_id' => 1)
));
```

In that function (db::q()) i check everything that got to be checked before creating the sql string and executing it.
By the way i think that it is not really needed. So i was thinking about just using a function `request_var($name, 'POST'/'GET')` that could get every $_POST and $_GET variables sent and escaping them so that i could just use:

```
$db->query("SELECT username FROM ".USERS_TABLE." WHERE user_id = 1");
```

. Is it enough? Should i use `db::q()` ? Should i use `request_var()` ? Should i use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been my experience you don't just do a blanket check on all POST/GET variables. I typically check at the time of creating the query for a couple reasons:

1. No excess overhead assuming it doesn't make it to a query that time
2. I know what the data needs to look at when I know what column it's going in (validate ints, strings, floats, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure you escape strings using the appropriate function for your database. For example, by using [`pg_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) to escape string values prior to inserting them into the database.

From your code snippet, it looks like you are accepting tables names as part of a GET / POST? Why does your front-end need to know about your database tables? Such knowledge should generally only be required of server-side code.

Comment: Nono, the tables are set by constants which are defined in another files. The query's examples is just to show you the functions. It's oblivious that the POST and GET vars are used for example set the $user_id of the query (in the above example set to 1).